# Null pointer exception depending on statement chaining in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito, criteria

I have a test method that is supposed to test the following method:

```
public class SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl implements UniqueConstraintValidator {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Criteria> buildValidationCriteria(Object entity, Serializable id, String[] propertyNames) {
        final SelectionVariant selectionVariant = (SelectionVariant) entity;
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SelectionVariant.class);

        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("client", selectionVariant.getClient()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("variant.variantName", selectionVariant.getVariant().getVariantName()));

        return new ArrayList<Criteria>(Arrays.asList(criteria));
    }

    @Required
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

which runs fine. But if I modify the lines as follows:

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SelectionVariant.class).add(Restrictions.eq("client", selectionVariant.getClient()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("variant.variantName", selectionVariant.getVariant().getVariantName()));
```

I will get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.innflow.ebtam.dao.hibernate.variant.SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl.buildValidationCriteria(SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl.java:35)
```

Why? What am I missing?

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImplTest {

    SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator
            = new SelectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidatorImpl();

    @Mock
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Mock
    private Session session;
    @Mock
    private Criteria criteria;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBuildValidationCriteria() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
        Mockito.when(session.createCriteria(SelectionVariant.class)).thenReturn(criteria);
        SelectionVariant selectionVariant = new SelectionVariant();
        Client client = new ClientBuilder().businessKey("HPD").description("desc").version(0).id(1L).build();
        selectionVariant.setClient(client);
        selectionVariantUniqueConstraintValidator.buildValidationCriteria(selectionVariant, null, null);
        Mockito.verify(criteria,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).add(Restrictions.eq("client", Mockito.any(Client.class)));
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you should test this kind of code against a real database with an integration test, instead of mocking

Comment: @artbristol Thanks, and yes you are right but the integration test is covered by different tests. I just want to make sure buildValidationCriteria adds the required Restrictions, nothing more. Do you still think this is somehow useless or wrong in any way?

Comment: If you find it useful to do both, then definitely continue to do so. I usually find when I get data-access code wrong, it's because I misunderstood how the database worked, and so I don't find it out until I use a real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mock `add` method of `Criteria`. Here is what happens here. In your first version you have mocked instance of criteria. When you invoke method `add()` it does nothing and returns `null` but it does not bother you because you do not use the return value.

However you do use the return value of `add()` in your second version. In order to make it working you should either:

1. make mockito to call real `add()` method \
2. mock `add()` method to make it to return the original criteria

For example:

```
when(criteria.add(any(Restrictions.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
```

or

```
when(criteria.add(any(Restrictions.class))).thenReturn(criteria)
```

(I am not sure that it should be `Restrictions.class`: it should be the class of `Restrictions.eq()`)